# How can I provide a default implementation of a function without causing warnings?

Tags: elixir

I want to provide a `LibraryModule` to be used like this:

```
defmodule ClientModule do
  use LibraryModule
end

ClientModule.do_something # should work
```

I want `LibraryModule` to provide a default implementation of `do_something/0`, which can be overridden in `ClientModule` by simply defining it there. However, when I do that right now, I get a compiler warning: "this clause cannot match because a previous clause at line X always matches".

It seems like `GenServer` does this, but I don't know how.

Comment: Before anyone asks: Yes, I asked and simultaneously answered this question. https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/ and there's a built-in checkbox for doing that.

Comment: didn't see the comment before answering!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Specifically for your case, something like:

#### LibraryModule

```
defmodule LibraryModule  do

  defmacro __using__(_) do
    quote([]) do
      @behaviour LibraryModule
      def do_something(), do: "Didn't do much but still"
      defoverridable [do_something: 0]
    end
  end

  @callback do_something() :: any
end
```

#### ClientModule

```
defmodule ClientModule do
  use LibraryModule
end
```

#### iex>

```
ClientModule.do_something()
# "Didn't do much but still"
```

**The `use LibraryModule`** will call the `__using__/1` macro, and then the section of code which is quoted is injected into your `ClientModule` and so the
`ClientModule` acquires a default implementation of the `do_something/0` callback function.

**The `__using__`** macro is very `useful` in writing libraries.

#### NewClientModule

```
defmodule NewClientModule do
  use LibraryModule

  def do_something(), do: "Something else"
end
```

#### iex

```
NewClientModule.do_something()
# "Something else"
```

Answer (score 1):

## Use `defoverridable`

[GenServer does it](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.3.0-rc.0/lib/elixir/lib/gen_server.ex#L481-L482) using [defoverridable](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.2/elixir/Kernel.html#defoverridable/1).

A highly-simplified snippet:

```
  defmacro __using__(_) do
    quote do
      def init(args) do
        {:ok, args}
      end

      defoverridable [init: 1]
    end
  end
```

Comment: From what version is it available?